# No returned value from find_all()

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Im trying to get a special number from this website, but I cant get anything returned from this specific class.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.bet365.com/#/AS/B1/I^16/J^1/"
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
urlopen(req).close()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

matcher = page_soup.find_all(class_="eur-ParticipantLinkIPPGEnhanced gl-Market_General-cn1 ")
print(page_soup)
```

When I do print(page_soup) I can not find the class that I am looking for, but when I am looking in dev-mode on Chrome I can. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The website is dynamically generated, so the data won't be there when you load it with BeautifulSoup. Consider using Selenium for this task.